# Rename multiple columns with series index using dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

My data frame looks like this

```
X0 <- c(11,2,3,4)
X1 <- c(10,2,3,4)
X2 <- c(8,2,3,4)
X3 <- c(4,6,3,4)
test <- data.frame(X0,X1,X2,X3)

  X0 X1 X2 X3
1 11 10  8  4
2  2  2  2  6
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
```

I would like to rename the first three columns using the character "t" and the series from 1:3.
I want my data frame to look like this

```
  t0 t1 t2 X3
1 11 10  8  4
2  2  2  2  6
3  3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4  4
```

*****EDIT*****
It works like this

```
test %>%
  rename_at(vars(X0:X2), list(~paste0("t", 0:2)))
```

Comment: The pipeline you proposed works for me.  Not sure what else you're looking for.

Comment: same: it works.

Comment: You are right, I just had a problem with my original data set. I leave just in case some finds it interesting in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or using `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
test %>% 
  rename_with(~ str_c('t', 0:2), X0:X2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option with `setnames`

```
setnames(setDT(test),1:3,function(v) gsub("X","t",v))
```